# Most Performant Android ViewGroup to Use For Independantly Positioned Children? - RelativeLayout vs FrameLayout

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I'm no Android expert but I am aware of discussions regarding the appropriate use of LinearLayout and RelativeLayout, keeping the view hierarchy as small as possible, avoid unnecessary passes of onMeasure(), etc.

Lets imagine I have two ImageView's that I want to position completely INDEPENDENTLY, the first in the center of the parent and the second in the bottom left of the parent.  (note this is a vastly simplified example of far more complex real life requirements).

The obvious way to solve this is using a RelativeLayout...

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/first_image" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/second_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However something keeps telling me that a RelativeLayout isn't appropriate in this situation because I don't want to organise the children relative to each other.  All I want to do is position the children according to the parent and I wonder if using a RelativeLayout causes some unnecessary layout calculations that I don't really require.

I am wondering if there is another ViewGroup type that would perform better?  Its totally possible to achieve what I want with a FrameLayout for example but I've no idea if this is more performant or if I am abusing the intent of a FrameLayout etc...

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/first_image" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/second_image" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Maybe there is another Layout type I am unaware of?

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

Given the information you have provided, the `FrameLayout` has a good chance of performing better. As you may have learned already watching ([Adam Powell quote in Google I/O 2013 conference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYtB6mlu7vA&t=2m03s)),

> [...] RelativeLayouts will measure child views more than once in order to solve some of the constraints you give it. So, being generic has a cost [...]

From what I read and understood, this is not guaranteed and it depends on the constraints you give it.

### Long answer

**It really depends**.

We all read [Romain Guy blog post : Android Layout Tricks #1](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html), who [said that most people misinterpret](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYtB6mlu7vA&t=1m48s) his [post](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/) and started using `RelativeLayout` everywhere.

This [post](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/), if you haven't read it, talks about how removing one hierarchy level using a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` which saves loading time in a list.

Basically, it means that if you don't need them, as you described it yourself

> [...] I have two ImageViews that I want to position completely INDEPENDENTLY [...]  I don't want to organize the children relative to each other

you should not use them because of that reason.

#### Concrete example of : "Don't use them if you don't need to."

For instance, in one of our applications, we have serious performance issues on devices running Gingerbread -- which we want to support.

Our most complex layout involves a vertical `ScrollView`, attached to the current activity, in which we have several containers and one `HorizontalScrollView` that displays images and information which are contained in a complex `LinearLayout`.

We started to replace the `LinearLayout` by `RelativeLayout`. The result: no obvious improvement -- equivalent or maybe worse.

Since that layout is fairly complex, adding more `RelativeLayout`s embedded in each other just increased the `onMeasure()` calls that were made for a single draw.

Even a small circular `ProgressBar` was now spamming the UI thread with several measure calls because it was in one of those embedded `RelativeLayout` which triggered recalculations of the whole view.